# C# Y Datagridview

Tags: c#

Hi everyone I have a question what happens is that I currently have a datagridview1 which has a "Ri" column as follows

```
Ri
0,6
0,4
0,9
0,1
1,8

double valor1 
double valor2
valor1=0,9 Valor2= 0,1
```

what I have to do is that between 0.9 and 0.1 say how many numbers there are in that range

Comment: I took a guess on the formatting, as your question is quite unclear. Please do read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Performing the steps in those articles will help get you the best possible answer.

Comment: What's the correct result when you have `0.6, 0.4, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.8` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean entries in the grid between the two provided values.

Your model should be populating the GridView from either a List or an Array.  Both of which allow you to get the index of an entry based on the value.

So, you can get both indexes and then do some subtraction.  Careful of the fact that indexes of 6 and 5 will tell you there is an entry between.